# Future Erosion Problem? Paver Patio

Tags: outdoor, patio, landscaping, pavers

QUESTION: Is this paver patio a future erosion issue?  Was this done properly?

DETAILS: Paver patio is elevated on 6"+ of base material at farthest point from the house. Paver edges are secured with edging now, but base is aggregate/sandy material extending only slightly beyond pavers.

BACKGROUND: I'm renovating a house and had a landscaper add a paver patio. He 'leveled' the ground, however, I'm concerned this will fall apart in time because nothing is set to contain the aggregate base.  He claims there is no issue.  A paver patio he installed for me at a different house was nearly flush with the ground, so I did not expect this.

[image: overview from back]

[image: overview from side]

[image: ~8" from Paver top to bottom of aggregate]

[image: Aggregate dropoff - Profile]

[image: Paver edging - gap in plastic and paver]

Comment: A close in picture of the edge would be helpful, but to my eye (and I'm no expert), it looks like that won't last 6 months. Unless those pavers are set in mortar/concrete, there's nothing holding the soldier course in place and they'll just fall off their bed and wander away. Usually there is some sort of edging (traditionally steel, though plastic will probably last longer) to hold that edge in place.

Comment: Or pressure treated lumber. Something. Also, those steps don't look good - first step half the rise of the other steps is a problem, and when you put something on top of the steps (assuming they currently have the open hollow sections in the cinderblocks as appears from the picture, but can't say 100%), the distance from the top step to the door will be less than the other steps - could have been planned better to get the heights right.

Comment: Good call on the steps! I'd guess that the last step height was _more_ even before the installation of the pavers. They seem to have chewed into that height.

Comment: @FreeMan, I've uploaded some new pictures.  There is plastic edging, but it is very low on the pavers.  Also not really tight to the pavers at any exposed points.  My biggest concern is the 6-8" bed of aggregate upon which it all sits.  I expect that might wash away fairly quickly.  No blocks or other means of retaining that.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact, correct.  The original pics did not have the cap stones on the block steps.  They are not evenly spaced.  Bottom step is 8" high, next two ~7.5", then ~4.25" for top step into the house.

Comment: I restored the original 2 pictures, as without them, none of the existing comments made sense, and it's good to have the overall view of the site. I'd agree that the sloped base doesn't look like it will last long. That's the kind of thing they do on the county roads around me and it doesn't last more than a year. If the raised patio is a surprise to you, then maybe you need to review what was written/drawn the contract with your guy and see if he did it wrong or you agreed to the wrong thing.